# Sous vide meat without seasoning - strong flavor

Tags: sous-vide

I tried the [beer cooler sous vide hack](http://www.seriouseats.com/2010/04/cook-your-meat-in-a-beer-cooler-the-worlds-best-sous-vide-hack.html) just now. On both a veal entrecote and a piece of lean beef braising meat. Both turned out OK, but as the sous vide technique does not impart flavor, most people found the veal a bit underwhelming.

So - if I want to serve an unseasoned piece of meat using this technique: what animal, and what cut, should I take for maximum inherent taste?

Comment: Given this question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6592/should-i-sear-meat-which-is-cooked-sous-vide-before-it-goes-in-the-bag-or-after - how did your searing work?

Comment: Unseared, but deliberately so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The beer cooler hack is not ideal for meat. The issue is the cooking time. I don't find Sous Vide to be particularly good for meats with low fat content that require short cooking time. The meat comes out perfectly cooked, which is nice (i.e. a steak medium rare from edge to edge), but you don't get any real wow factor from the flavor or texture. Where meats start to get really interesting, in my opinion, is long cook times. Tougher cuts of meat that require longer cooking (short ribs, flank steak, ribs, roasts) come out meltingly tender with all the lovely meaty flavor of the cut **and** you can cook them medium rare. These take 12-24 hours though, and I don't think the beer cooler hack would work for that (at least not without a lot of tending).

However, the beer cooler hack should work *very* well for seafood, which has much shorter cooking times. Here the temperature control and the vacuum sealing is what really makes a difference. You can get some wonderfully novel textures out of seafood and very subtle complex tastes without anything being "fishy". I'd recommend you try one of the following:

- Salmon Mi-Cuit - cook salmon at 113F / 45C for about 35 minutes. This is delicious. Somewhere between sashimi and cooked, great texture and a fantastic flavor.
- Lobster - cook the tail meat (no shell) at 140F / 60C for 15 - 20 minutes. Do not let this one go long. The lobster will turn to mush and gets disgusting.
- Halibut - cook at 140F / 60C for about 35 minutes. Great texture and flavor. Very moist. Essentially "perfectly cooked" fish.

Note that the first two **do not reach pasteurization levels**. You should use sushi grade fish and not serve to anyone who is immune compromised.

You could also try chicken breasts. I know a couple of people who rave about chicken because of how moist it comes out, but I've never had much luck with it (the few times I've tried).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a tough but flavorful cut of beef, like chuck. I like my beef rare, so I keep the temps on the low side. It's the time - hours or even days - that break down the connective tissues that make these cuts tough. I find that it's easy to over do this, and there is such as thing as meat that's too tender.

I add marinades, salt and whatever flavorings to the meat inside a zip-lock freezer bag, immerse it all in water to push the air out of the bag and then seal it.

I don't know what the beer-cooler hack is, but I use a cooler with a digital temp controller and replacement 110 volt heating element for a hot water heater. The whole setup costs about $30-40USD and works great.

Also, before serving hit the meat with a butane torch to give it some browning and flavor. Propane will add a garlic-like taste from the leak-detecting agents that aren't good. If you're lucky enough to have an alcohol blow torch, that would work too. I'm not even going to think of a gasoline (petrol) torch. Hydrogen would be fabulous.