# Should I sear meat which is cooked sous vide before it goes in the bag, or after?

Tags: sous-vide

After reading the beer cooler sous vide hack, I'm tempted to try it probably with duck, but maybe with steak.

Should I sear my duck/steak first before I put it in the bag, or afterwards, and why?  Or does it not make a difference?

Comment: If your doing duck you may want to consider removing the skin/fat layer and cooking/crisping that separately (between two sheet pans in the oven works great) because that's going to be very rubbery and chewy and will retain so much moisture you run the risk of overcooking your duck breast when trying to achieve a proper sear. SV methods are not universal since there is so much variation between proteins.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a bit of googling, I found [this](http://www.cookingissues.com/primers/sous-vide/purdy-pictures-the-charts/) which suggests that searing twice (both before and after) might be preferable.

Comment: That link is pretty awesome.

Comment: not to mention too much work. ;o)

Comment: Pull some of that data in here :)

Comment: Wow...just wow.  +1 for that incredible link.

Comment: yeah, I've read that blog since I saw a link to it on here a while back, but had never seen that article before.  most of what I've read on there is pure gold though

Comment: Nice drawings there!

Comment: That link has gone now, does anyone know if there is another copy?

Comment: @vwiggins : http://web.archive.org/web/20100722165345/http://www.cookingissues.com/primers/sous-vide/purdy-pictures-the-charts/

Comment: Thanks joe. @steinbach I understand your reasons but if you look at the link you can see why I didn't include the info from the link.

Comment: Cooking issues is back online BTW.

Answer (score 6):

I have seen it done both ways. I prefer mine seared after it has cooked to preserve the crispness of the sear. If you sear first then sous-vide the crispness will be gone from the crust. This is really apparent with steaks.

Comment: I think the lack of crispness on the duck skin would detract a lot. That is always one of the appealing parts of the duck: the nice brown, crisp skin with the fat layer underneath.

Comment: yeah I think for duck the skin would have to be crisped up after cooking, unless it was cooked with the skin off, and the skin/fat was crisped up separately.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to sear it after. You get a decent additional taste from the Maillard reaction regardless of whether you do it before or after. However, even though your steak isn't directly in contact with the water, it will shed juices during the cooking process. If you sear first, then the meat sits in it's own juices. This means that the sear isn't crunchy when you're ready to eat. I personally like the texture difference enough to sear only after I've cooked it sous vide.

Searing after will also help your presentation. Meat doesn't always look particularly appetizing when it comes out of the sous vide. Throwing a sear on makes it look much better.

Answer (score 3):

I sear before and after.

I blow torch the meat before putting it into the bags. The flame is very hot (around 1.500C) and only affects the surface, it does not cook the meat. This kills any bacteria you might have on the surface of your cut before bagging it.

I do my steaks (filet or entrecote) at 50-52C, which is still in the danger zone. 55C and enough time kills most germs, though I tend to find that just a little too medium for my taste. I take the bags out just before serving, pat dry and sear quickly over high heat in a cast iron skillet. Usually 30s per side flipping every 15 seconds in order not to cook the meat much further.